# In Xamarin.Android, how to get NewApi Lint warnings

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm developing a Xamarin.Android app where I need to support older devices.

Setting `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` is easy, but is there any way I can get compile time warnings/errors about APIs introduced since `minSdkVersion`, so I can code around those issues?

Basically, I want the equivalent to the `NewApi` Lint warnings on native Android.

Comment: I don't believe there is support for this. Android supports a very basic linter. You should be able to turn this on by adding a `<AndroidLintEnabled>true</AndroidLintEnabled>` property in your `.csproj`. https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/blob/9e6b04703bd50fe524bed47a5b8eed67ee93d0f5/src/Xamarin.Android.Build.Tasks/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets#L879

Comment: @JonDouglas, I've tried that. It's almost unworkable. Deploys take forever (I've never managed to see one to completion). Fortunately, NewApi errors are some of the first reported, and I was able to validate my apps API usage. But this functionality is severely lacking.

Comment: Feel free to report a bug on https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/ to help extend the functionality. As mentioned earlier, the Xamarin.Android linter is very basic in functionality AFAIK!